# Конфиг apache для всех субдоменов

Tags: apache, config

Я получил Wildcard SSL-сертификат для своих субдоменов, но что мне теперь нужно прописать в конфигурационном файле домена, если сертификат распространяется исключительно на поддомены, а для основного домена мне нужно использовать другой сертификат? Сейчас файл выглядит так:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin me@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/subd/%1"
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

И когда я заходу на любой поддомен, сертификат на нем есть. Что мне следует написать, чтобы отдельно добавить строчки установки сертификата только на основной домен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите здесь в качестве servername "www.example.com", а на example.com заведите другой VirtualHost.